# Ubuntu 12.04 desktop

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04

In Ubuntu 12.04 desktop version, after editing the network interface settings from GUI, where these settings are stored?

I am not finding the same in /etc/network/interfaces file.

Thank you,
Namith

Comment: You should try on askubuntu.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is stored on `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` folder. There are files for each of your network connection.

Answer (score 0):

On a standard desktop installation using Network Manager, the /etc/network/interfaces file isn't used for much. The only contents are:
Code:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

You can save this by running gedit as root with the terminal command

```
gksudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Then just paste the 2 lines and save the file